# Jquery можно ли выбрать текст который не находится ни в одном элементе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли выбрать и изменить "usd" без оборачивания его в какой то элемент?

```html
<strong>
   <em>Цена</em>: <span id="js_price">65</span> usd
</strong>
```

Comment: Разобрался) Очень затупил)

Comment: конечно можно. Тут уже было несколько вопросов про это

Comment: @АлександрГонтарь, если вы нашли решение своего вопроса, вы можете ответить на него и пометить свой ответ как решение.

Comment: или же Вы можете удалить вопрос за ненадобностью. только не оставляйте его открытым и/или без решения пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно *"выбрать текст, который не находится ни в одном элементе"*, то можно воспользоваться следующим приемом:

```
$("strong")
    .clone()    // клонируем элемент
    .children() // выделяем все дочерние элементы
    .remove()   // удаляем все дочерние элементы
    .end()      // вернуться к выбранному элементу
    .text();
```

Но в вашем примере выйдет: `":  usd"`. Поэтому после вызова текст можно добавить:

```
// .text()
   .substring(1) // удаляем ":"
   .trim(); // удаляем пробемы
```